# Failure in obtaining new access token after expiration of old token using WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

On expiration of access token I have been facing a peculiar problem wherein sometimes my calls are failing with a 401 error(Access token expired). As you would expect I should get a new token using refresh_token grant through OAuth2TokenRelayFilter. This works until a certain point after which the token stops refreshing. And the weird thing is on inspection I found that the token that expired was not the token used just previously, it was the first token that was issued on program run.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens have some expiry time. But you can configure the access tokens expiry time in service provider level.

Please refer to this document to configure access tokens and refresh tokens expiry time in service provider level https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On

The refresh token grant can be used when the current access token is expired or when a new access token is needed. The refresh token is renewed when the refresh grant is used to get an access token. In WSO2 Identity server, A new refresh token is issued for refresh grant with a new expiry time and the previous refresh token is made inactive and can no longer be used.

There is a **RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant** configuration to disable this property in the identity.xml file. By default this **RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant** config in enabled true.

Due to this for each refresh grant request, the previous refresh token becomes inactive and a new refresh token will be issued with a new access token. You can disable the config in identity.xml file as below if you don't want to renew refresh tokens per request. Due to this **RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant** property, if you use a previously issued refresh token will become inactive and you can't use that refresh token to refresh to access tokens further.

`<RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant>false</RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant>`

Please refer to this document to refer further about refresh tokens https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Refresh+Token+Grant

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have actually implemented both of the above. My problem is a specific case. In the normal scenario after a access token expires a new one is generated using refresh token, This works for me a few times after which it stops working. It says access token expired and something odd that happens is instead of failing with the last token it fails with the first token that was issued in this run.

Comment: Access_token will expire after the expiry time. That is expected behaviour. Can you please elaborate this "It says access token expired and something odd that happens is instead of failing with the last token it fails with the first token that was issued in this run" ?

Comment: Lets say I have a access_token expiry time of 5 minutes. Also i should mention I am using a self contained access_token.So I get a access_token "A" and refresh token "B". After 5 minutes it uses refresh_token "B" to generate a new access_token "C" and refresh_token "D". After 5 minutes it uses refresh_token "D" to generate a new access_token "E" and refresh_token "F".It goes on like this, working perfectly, till after some time it stops working. And in the chrome browser I can see "Access token expired : A". Not the last token but the first one.Also there is no error on the console..